# How to center the built in React calendar in css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have currently implemented the React calendar, but its glued to the left side of the screen regardless of what i change in the css file.

I have tried to individually change each component and nothing has been changed. The code below is before i added in all the aligment: center. The code below consists of the jsx and the css files

```
/* Base calendar styling */
.react-calendar {
    width: 350px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #a0a096;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.125em;
}

/* Calendar styling for double views */
.react-calendar--doubleView {
    width: 700px;
}

.react-calendar--doubleView .react-calendar__viewContainer {
    display: flex;
    margin: -0.5em;
}

.react-calendar--doubleView .react-calendar__viewContainer > * {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

/* Box sizing for all elements */
.react-calendar,
.react-calendar *,
.react-calendar *:before,
.react-calendar *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

/* Button styling */
.react-calendar button {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

/* Button hover effect */
.react-calendar button:enabled:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Navigation bar */
.react-calendar__navigation {
    height: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.react-calendar__navigation button {
    min-width: 44px;
    background: none;
}

/* Navigation button hover and disabled styles */
.react-calendar__navigation button:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__navigation button:enabled:focus {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.react-calendar__navigation button[disabled] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Weekday labels in month view */
.react-calendar__month-view__weekdays {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.react-calendar__month-view__weekdays__weekday {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

/* Week numbers in month view */
.react-calendar__month-view__weekNumbers {
    font-weight: bold;

}

.react-calendar__month-view__weekNumbers .react-calendar__tile {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    padding: calc(0.75em / 0.75) calc(0.5em / 0.75);
}

/* Weekend day styling */
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--weekend {
    color: #d10000;
}

/* Neighboring month day styling */
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--neighboringMonth {
    color: #757575;
}

/* Year, decade, and century view tile padding */
.react-calendar__year-view .react-calendar__tile,
.react-calendar__decade-view .react-calendar__tile,
.react-calendar__century-view .react-calendar__tile {
    padding: 2em 0.5em;

}

/* Calendar tile styling */
.react-calendar__tile {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.75em 0.5em;
    background: none;
}

/* Disabled tile styling */
.react-calendar__tile:disabled {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Enabled tile hover and focus styles */
.react-calendar__tile:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile:enabled:focus {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

/* Current date tile styling */
.react-calendar__tile--now {
    background: #ffff76;
}

.react-calendar__tile--now:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--now:enabled:focus {
    background: #ffffa9;
}

/* Active date tile styling */
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive {
    background: #76baff;
}

.react-calendar__tile--hasActive:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--hasActive:enabled:focus {
    background: #a9d4ff;
}

/* Active tile styling */
.react-calendar__tile--active {
    background: #006edc;
    color: white;
}

.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:hover,
.react-calendar__tile--active:enabled:focus {
    background: #1087ff;
}

/* Select range mode tile hover style */
.react-calendar--selectRange .react-calendar__tile--hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;

}

export default function Calendar(){
    const[date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

    return(
      <div className= "calendar">
          <h2>Job Estimator and Scheduler</h2> 
          {/*This is the header for the calendar */}
          <div className="calendar-container">
              <Calender onChange={setDate} value={date}/>
          </div>
          <div className="text-center">
              Selected date: {date.toDateString()}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: A good recommendation would be to also look at the documentation for [CSS Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) as they both provide the ability to easily center the content.

Example: `justify-content: center` & `align-items: center`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chnage the position of any div (with width) to be in center of the screen, use the following code:

```css
.in-center-div {
  margin: 40px auto auto;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
}

.in-center-div:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px
}

,
```

```html
<div class="in-center-div">
  div content
  <br/>
  <br/> div content
</div>
```

So, just wrap your code with the container div with "in-center-div" className.